# Mac Pro GUI frequently hangs for two-to-ten minutes

Tags: macos, performance, mac-pro

I am experiencing repeated hangs on my Mac Pro.

**Symptoms:**

- The entire GUI hangs with the exception of the mouse cursor
- I *can* move the mouse cursor
- I can't scroll
- I can't select a different window
- I can't alt-tab
- The menus are unresponsive
- The clock in the menu bar stops updating during the hang
- If music or a video is playing when the hang occurs, the audio portion continues playing and the video portion stops. Note that the source of the A/V doesn't matter. It can be a local file or a stream
- The beach ball cursor is not displayed unless it was already displayed prior to the hang
- These hangs last anywhere from two to ten minutes, usually three to five
- This appears to be completely random. Some days it doesn't happen at all while other days it happens constantly
- Some number of GUI events do queue up and are processed when the hang ends (I haven't attempted to count how many)

**Things I've Tried:**

- Running Activity Monitor; it stops updating during the hang so no help there.
- Logging in from another machine via VNC and running Activity Monitor from there; same results as running it locally
- Running htop; stops updating during the hang
- Logging in from another machine via SSH and running htop: same results as running it locally
- I've examined the logs and found nothing that appears to be related (note that I'm a professional software developer with 40+ years of experience and am pretty comfortable looking at log files)
- Checked the S.M.A.R.T status of the disk drives with smartctl; no errors reported on three drives, a couple of errors (that I don't understand), on the forth drive but it reports as passed
- Checked for RAM errors; no errors reported
- Stopped various applications that are potentially resource-hungry (BackBlaze Backup, Time Machine, the Spotlight indexer, VMware Fusion, etc.)
- Wrote a shell script to run top with output to a file; it doesn't run during the hang even if started as a daemon (i.e., no attached terminal)

**Other Information:**

- I typically have 20-30 applications running at any given time although only the "front" application, Fusion, whatever JavaScript is happening in the background in the browsers, and possibly a music player are actually active at any given time. Oh. and Folding at Home once in a while.
- This machine typically runs at more than 90% idle CPU even with multiple virtual machines running.
- I have never seen the "Memory Pressure" anything but green.
- All of the disks have plenty of free space.

**More on the S.M.A.R.T. scan:**

They are apparently transient. I have since run both "short" and "long" self-tests on the drive that showed errors and they completed with no errors.

**System Configuration:**

- Mac Pro (mid 2010)
- Two 3.46GHz 6-core Intel Xeon CPUs
- 64GB 1333MHz DDR3 ECC RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760 4GB with four monitors
- System disk: 1TB internal Western Digital Caviar Black
- Three 4TB internal Seagate drives for data
- External 1TB USB drive for TimeMachine
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (this has been happening for the past few updates, I think before 10.14)

Comment: SMART status is like the "check engine" light on your car.  If it comes on - something's definitely wrong. However, it could be off and you still have issues.  If you got errors using SMART, your hard drive is failing.  Get something like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/).  It's free for diagnostics, but any recovery is free.  But, based on what you said, you have a failing drive.

Comment: Ran the DiskDrill SMART utility and it shows the drives to be clean.

Comment: Can you post the report?

Comment: Actually, at this point I'm fairly sure it's not a problem with the disks. After a couple of hangs yesterday I checked on the disks (with both DiskDrill and smartctl. There were no new errors. The real issue here is the hangs. Thanks.